# My new license information does not show when I run jlicensinginfo on jBASE

Tags: jbase

I just installed a standard license on jBASE but when I run jlicensinginfo it doesn't show the license as being changed. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What jBASE version you are running? How did you install the license (with what commands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally need to run "jLicenseUpgrade -r" to refresh shared memory before the new licensing information is available:

https://docs.zumasys.com/jbase/administration/installation-guides/licensing-a-jbase-system/#examples

Then use "jlicensinginfo -V" to verify that the license details are correct.

Mike